# Illegal Instruction:4 when using pynput keyboard with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading, pynput

I was trying to use pynput to create a automatic keyboard typer with tkinter. The pynput keyboard typer is made using a custom thread (note: I followed a certain tutorial that I can't find now). When executed by itself, it works fine, but when executed with tkinter, it creates a `Illegal Instruction: 4` error.

Edit: as per @Karl's recommendation, I made a minimum example. The following code snippet re-creates the exact same issue:

```
import tkinter,threading,pynput,time
keyb = pynput.keyboard.Controller()
global thread_save
def typer(*args):
    while True:
        # print("spam")
        keyb.type("hi")
        time.sleep(0.1)
def beginning(*args):
    global thread_saved
    print("pressed")
    thread_saved = threading.Thread(target=typer)
    thread_saved.start()
    thread_saved.run()
root = tkinter.Tk()
but = tkinter.Button(text="Begin",master=root)
but.bind("<1>",beginning)
but.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Expected Result: after clicking the button, the word"hi" will be typed over and over on the keyboard

Current Result:
program crashes with Illegal Instruction:4

System version:

Macos 10.15.7

Intel Mac

packages:

```
pynput==1.7.6
pyobjc-core==10.0
pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices==10.0
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==10.0
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==10.0
six==1.16.0
```

Comment: I heard that there are certain problems in pynput with MacOs, but the behavior , in my opinion, suggests that tkinter is intefering with pynput

Comment: Is it possible you did the "freeze" on an M1 or M2 Mac and you're now trying to use it on an x86 Mac?

Comment: @TimRoberts I only have one mac(x86)...

Comment: Please read [mre] and try to create *minimal* steps to reproduce the problem *from scratch*.

Comment: Thank you @KarlKnechtel . I have edited my question.

Comment: Now that we see the source, the problem is clear.  You CANNOT do UI-stuff in a secondary thread.  This is true for ALL UI frameworks.  It sometimes works on Windows, it sometimes works on Linux, but it NEVER works on a Mac.  You need to use `root.after` to ask for a callback after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading the comments, I'm still unable to resolve the problem via threads. However, I was sucessfull in using child processes.Thanks to @Tim Roberts for your comment.

Comment: Can you provide the solution in detail ?